# mixed scala/java project, which compile first?

Tags: java, scala, maven, scala-maven-plugin

There are some existing similar questions based on codes, but I want to ask in a more general way.

Suppose there are java source code and scala source code, seems `scala-maven-plugin` is to be added.

1. So is there a default config which one is compiled first, scala or java?
2. If we want scala code depends on java, or the opposite, how to do it? (like `scala-compile-first` in plugin?)
3. Is is possible that some scala code depends on java, while some java code also depends on scala?

Comment: Item #3 is doable by letting all code (Java and Scala) be compiled with the scala plugin. At least in Gradle that's possible, I'd be surprised if the Maven plugin can't do that.

Comment: If item #3 is true you have a circular dependency which would prevent your compilation... I would make separate modules one with Java code one with Scala code...

Comment: @khmarbaise assume no circular dependency exists, still not doable?

Comment: If no deps than the order of deps will give you the reverse order of compilation...

Comment: Also note that you don't necessarily need Scala Maven plugin: SBT is able to compile Java as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. java is compiled first, if both compilation are run in their default phase
2. scala depends of java, nothing to customize, it's the default behavior. If java depends of scala you should force the compilation of scala code during a phase before like `process-resources`.
3. Yes you can have "mixed" scala/java, in this case scala compiler should run before and be aware of java source (the scala compiler will parse them to extract API). It's the same configuration than scala first

```xml
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
    ...
```

For example see the docs: [Mixed Java/Scala Projects – scala-maven-plugin](https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html) or the integration test [scala-maven-plugin/src/it at master · davidB/scala-maven-plugin](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it)

Comment: The integration test you post https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it/testJavaAndScala is a very good example